# Emails are not being processed in hook_node_presave and hook_node_insert

Tags: 7, emails

I'm using [htmlmail](https://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) module. I'm trying to send an email after node save. So I put drupal_mail() into hook_node_insert() or hook_node_presave(), but when I'm doing this, the body of my emailes are empty.

The source looks literally like this:

```
<div class="htmlmail-body">
</div>
```

The templates are not processed. The hook_preprocess_htmlmail() function in template.php is not beeing invoked. I'm using different templates for different mail keys.

Now the funny thing is that when I'm using the same drupal_mail() in hook_cron() it just works as expected. I have no idea how I can debug this. Any ideas (for example where to put a debuggers break for further diagnosis)?

**Added #1**:
It appears that only htmlmail.tpl.php is being used instead of my module and key specific templates that works when I'm sending mails from cron.

**Added #2**:
Code in hook_cron() and in hook_node_presave() is the same:

```
$receipents = array( variable_get('site_mail', 'example@example.com') );
$params = array();
drupal_mail('bonds_cron', "create_payments__client", implode(', ', $receipents), language_default(), $params, variable_get('site_mail', 'example@example.com'), true);
```

The difference is that in hook_cron() it works, and in hook_node_presave() it doesn't. I was trying to change double "__" into one, thinking that maybe it's something with picking up templates, but without success. I'm searching now for place in core code, when I could put a break to see what is going on when picking up those templates but I cannot find it. :/

**Added #3**:
template_preprocess_htmlmail() run just fine. The proper template suggestion is added there.

**Added #4**:
I added `var_dump($items)` before the end of htmlmail_theme() function. When clearing cache I got this output:

```
array(11) {
  'htmlmail__bonds-cron__create_payments__admin' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(44) "htmlmail--bonds-cron--create_payments__admin"
    'path' =>
    string(35) "sites/default/themes/bond/templates"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
  'htmlmail__bonds-cron__create_payments__agent' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(44) "htmlmail--bonds-cron--create_payments__agent"
    'path' =>
    string(35) "sites/default/themes/bond/templates"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
  'htmlmail__bonds-cron__create_payments__client' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(45) "htmlmail--bonds-cron--create_payments__client"
    'path' =>
    string(35) "sites/default/themes/bond/templates"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
  'htmlmail__bonds-cron__payments_alert__admin' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(43) "htmlmail--bonds-cron--payments_alert__admin"
    'path' =>
    string(35) "sites/default/themes/bond/templates"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
  'htmlmail__bonds-cron__payments_alert__agent' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(43) "htmlmail--bonds-cron--payments_alert__agent"
    'path' =>
    string(35) "sites/default/themes/bond/templates"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
  'htmlmail__bonds-cron__payments_alert__client' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(44) "htmlmail--bonds-cron--payments_alert__client"
    'path' =>
    string(35) "sites/default/themes/bond/templates"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
  'htmlmail__bonds-cron__tax_alert__admin' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(38) "htmlmail--bonds-cron--tax_alert__admin"
    'path' =>
    string(35) "sites/default/themes/bond/templates"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
  'htmlmail__htmlmail' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(18) "htmlmail--htmlmail"
    'path' =>
    string(26) "sites/all/modules/htmlmail"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
  'htmlmail__simplenews' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(20) "htmlmail--simplenews"
    'path' =>
    string(26) "sites/all/modules/htmlmail"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
  'htmlmail__user__password_reset' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(30) "htmlmail--user--password_reset"
    'path' =>
    string(35) "sites/default/themes/bond/templates"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
  'htmlmail' =>
  array(4) {
    'variables' =>
    array(1) {
      'message' =>
      array(0) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'template' =>
    string(8) "htmlmail"
    'path' =>
    string(35) "sites/default/themes/bond/templates"
    'theme path' =>
    string(25) "sites/default/themes/bond"
  }
}
```

Seems ok for me.

Comment: Can you add the code you're using, that's not working, to send the email in the node api hooks. Otherwise impossible to debug.

Comment: Yes please post the actual code as well. It sounds like you are not implementing hook_mail which is essential to set the body, subject and other parameters if the email.

Comment: I added more code, but there is not much to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after digging VERY deep in theme.inc code I found the problem. I named my templates "htmlmail--bonds-cron--create_payments__client" and I should "htmlmail--bonds_cron--create_payments__client" (notice underscore instead of dash). Replacing underscore with dash made anomalies in ThemeRegistry storage, probably caused by string translations (of template names) in theme.inc . The consequence was this very strange different drupal_mail behaviour in different hooks. I hope it will help someone.